# Can somone showme how to do this in Python

Tags: python

So this piece of code is to show the number in word format when the user inputs digits.So I get how this piece of code work but I want to add something to it.I want to make the code so that when you input the digits and the results come out but after that, I want to make the user be able to input another line of digits and get the results.And when the user is done the user could input "Quit" and the program ends.

```
phone = input('Phone> ')
key_map = {
    "0": "Zero",
    "1": "One",
    "2": "Two",
    "3": "Three",
    "4": "Four",
    "5": "Five",
    "6": "Six",
    "7": "Seven",
    "8": "Eight",
    "9": "Nine"
}
output = ""
for number in phone:
    output += key_map.get(number, "!") + " "
print(output)
```

Comment: Do you know how to use loops? You already use one kind in this particular program. Can you explain how *that* one works?

Comment: Use a `while` loop. If `phone == 'Quit'`, you want to exit the loop instead of trying to format it using `key_map`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing you're using Python 3.8+ (and you certainly should be) then:

```
key_map = {
    "0": "Zero",
    "1": "One",
    "2": "Two",
    "3": "Three",
    "4": "Four",
    "5": "Five",
    "6": "Six",
    "7": "Seven",
    "8": "Eight",
    "9": "Nine"
}

while (p := input('Phone number: ')) != 'Quit':
    print(*[key_map.get(n, '!') for n in p])
```